# Kак через terminal (cmd) запустить скрипт и тестировать?

Tags: python, cmd, консоль

```
def IsPowerOf2(n):
    return (n!=0 and (n & (n-1)==0))


a = int(input())


if IsPowerOf2(a):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Kак через terminal (cmd)  запустить скрипт и тестировать код?
Надо автоматически вводить значения (c базы данных) в terminal и записать ответ с терминала в файл.

Comment: python path\to\your\script.py

Comment: А что касается базы данных - поясните какую именно базу данных вы хотите использовать

Comment: Код не нужно вставлять в виде скриншота, добавьте в вопрос обычный код текстом